# Cross-Divided Screen - Android

Tags: android, layout, screen, divide

I want to make cross-divided screen with two images and half of them are seen for each of them. But I couldn't find any sample nor any tutorial about it.

CROSS-DIVIDED SAMPLE:

[image]

**EDIT:** They need to have click-events also seperately.

Comment: Did u find any solution?

Comment: Not yet. I even don't decide which layout model I should use. I'm still waiting an solution which may come from here. @Jas

Comment: Do you want to add click events to your images? Or you are just showing the images?

Comment: Yeah I want to add it to them seperately. @Jas

Comment: you mean you want to add click events?